# Get the search box query from Menu in Action bar (In a Single Activity) on Button click?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

[image]

I wanna to submit Query for search in Action-bar search input pane  From **Activity A** and also want to get the Submitted Query in the same activity(**Activity A**) on Button Click .Need Tutorial for That ...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setOnQueryTextListener%28android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener%29). You need to setOnQueryTextListener and program whatever you want inside this method.

I made this code in my app:

```
public abstract class FragmentWithSearch extends SherlockFragment implements
        OnQueryTextListener {
    public SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        // Create the search view
        searchView = new SearchView(getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar()
                .getThemedContext());
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search…");
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);    
        menu.add("Search").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_search)
                .setActionView(searchView)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            ...
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro I want the Deafult Search of Menu in Actionbar .... Can you help me on that business